# How to add dynamic arguement in dynamic method JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Please see the below example code

```
var Abc = {
    id:0,
    title:null
};
var name = 'Sri'
Abc['conf'] = {};
Abc['setName']=function(name){this.title = name}; //1
Abc['setName']="function("+name+"){this.title = "+name+"}";  //2
console.log(Abc);
```

If i use //1 it adds method correctly
if i use //2 it adds a property instead a method. The argument is dynamic therefore //2 is required. But it adds a double quotes internally like -
"function(sri){this.title = sri}". So it becomes property.

Any idea

Comment: What does it matter what the parameter is called? Creating functions dynamically is rarely necessary. If you explain which problem you are trying to solve with this, we might be able to help you better. Otherwise, without more information, I'd recommend to use `//1`.

Comment: We need to add some properties and methods dynamically to an existing JavaScript object. We have an API which returns properties, methods in JSON string.

Comment: *"We need to add some properties and methods dynamically to an existing JavaScript object."* That's fine. That's what `//1` is doing. You haven't explained why the *parameter name* has to be named dynamically. I believe you have some misunderstanding here, but I don't know yet what it is. What do you want the `Abc` to look like in the end?

Comment: because different properties and methods load based on request. It is not static.

Comment: example api call - api/plugin/d4/bar - here bar is dynamic. So it loads different properties when last parameter is different.

Comment: I don't think you get my point. Lets look at an example: What is the difference between `function foo(name){this.title = name} //1` and `function bar(Sri){this.title = Sri} //2`? Is there a difference between calling `foo('test')` or `bar('test')`? Or do those functions perform the same operation?

Comment: In //1 argument is passed as name. But it should pass the name's value that is 'Sri'. So concatenate the name variable in //2 approach. It is taking the value. But due double quotes it become property. That is the different between both the functions.

Comment: *"But it should pass the name's value that is 'Sri'"* I think you may be confusing the *name* of a variable with the *value* of a variable? If you want to set the name of the object to the value `"Sri"`, then all you need is `Abc.setName=function(name){this.title = name};` and call it with `Abc.setName(name)` (where `var name = "Sri"`).

Comment: A sniper from real code 

GD.ReportVisualization.loadConfigs(chartData,function(conf){
                $.each( conf, function( key, value ) {
                        _this.report[key] = "function("+value+"){this."+value+"="+value+"}"
                    
                });
            });

Comment: If `key = "foo"` and `value = "bar"`, the function you want to create would look like `_this.report.foo = function(bar){this.bar = bar}`. I.e. if you later call `_this.report.foo(42)`, it would set `_this.report.bar` to `42`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Exactly you are correct

Comment: Then you should simply do `_this.report[key]= function(x){this[value]= x}`. The parameter name doesn't matter, which is what I said from the very beginning.

Comment: Seems. It is going to work. I need some more time. i ll update after some time.

Comment: Thanks Felix. We have changed our plan to load configuration through APIs. Instead we will put the configuration in client side and be loaded when required. Basically i am PHP developer, new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want but if you need to turn a string into a function, you could do this in an explicit way:

```
Abc['setName'] = new Function( name, "this.title = "+name );  //2
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to `function() { function(<name>) { this.title = <name>; } }`, i.e. this just creates a function that contains a function and even that's invalid since the inner function doesn't have a name. I guess you mean `new Function(name, "this.title = "+name)`.

Comment: @Wiktor -- SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks, forgot the constructor signature.

Comment: setName                       anonymous(sri) from firebug console

Comment: @manashb: It's not clear what you mean by this comment. Is this a confirmation? A problem?

Comment: this is console output after making changes as per Wiktor. this should be function instead of  anonymous

Comment: @manashb: "anonymous" simply means that the function doesn't have a name, which is correct. Nothing wrong about that.